# Why my GPU program can execute, although the number of blocks exceeds the number of resident blocks?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm working on GPU Tesla M6. According to its datasheet, Tesla M6 has 12 multiprocessors, and each of them holds a maximum of 32 resident blocks. So the total maximum number of blocks resident on the entire device is 384.

Now, I have a data matrix with size (512,1408). I wrote a kernel, and set the number of threads per block to 64 (1D block, one data element per thread), so the 1D gird size is 512*1408/64 = 11264 blocks, which is far beyond the number of resident blocks on the GPU. However, the whole program still can run and output correct results.

I wonder why the code can execute, although the real number of blocks exceed the resident one? Does it mean performance deterioration? Could you explain it detailedly to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GPU can hold many more blocks than what can be resident according to your calculation.

The GPU loads up as many blocks as it can on SMs, and the remainder wait in a queue.  As blocks finish their work on SMs and retire, they open up space for new blocks to be selected from the queue and made "resident".  Eventually, the GPU processes all blocks this way.

There isn't anything necessarily wrong with this approach; it is typical for GPU programming. It does not necessarily mean performance deterioration.  However, one approach to tuning kernels for maximum performance is to choose the number of blocks based on how many can be "resident".  The calculation of how many can be resident, if properly done, is more complex than what you have outlined.  It requires occupancy analysis.  CUDA provides an [occupancy API](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-occupancy-api-simplifies-launch-configuration/) to do this analysis at runtime.

This approach will also require design of a kernel that can get work done with an arbitrary or fixed size grid, rather than a grid size selected based on the problem size.  One typical approach for this is a [grid-stride loop](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).

If you combine a kernel design like grid-stride loop, with a choice of blocks at runtime based on occupancy analysis, then you can get your work done with only the blocks that are "resident" on the GPU; none need be in the queue, waiting.  This may or may not have any tangible performance benefits.  Only by benchmarking will you know for sure.

I suggest reading both articles I linked before asking follow-up questions.  There are also many questions on the `cuda` tag discussing the concepts in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Threads in a thread blocks can have dependencies on each other. Programming models such as cooperative groups allow for large groups than a thread block. The number of thread blocks in a Grid can be orders of magnitude greater than the number of resident thread blocks (e.g. Minimum is 1 Thread Block, GV100 supports 84 x 32 2688 resident thread blocks).

The compute work distributor assigns thread blocks to SMs. If the grid is preempted the state is saved and later restored. When all threads in a thread block complete the thread block resources are released (warp slots, registers, shared memory) and the the compute work distributor is notified. The compute work distributor will continue to assign thread blocks to SMs until all work in the grid completes.

Comment: Thread blocks _can_ have dependencies, since they share global memory. Also, it is not inherently guaranteed for a block to remain on the same physical SM throughout its life. It might be in practice, but as a programmer, you don't need this assumption nor can you make much use of it. -1